# Equivalent bounded-realness in time domain (MIMO case)

Tags: matrices, fourier-transform, control-theory

Let $G(j\omega)=C(j\omega I-A)^{-1}B+D \in \mathbb{C}^{m\times n}$ be the transfer function (multi-input multi-output) matrix of state space representation.

We know if $G(j\omega)$ is called bounded-real if $G(j\omega)^*G(j\omega)\leq \gamma I$ with $\gamma>0$.

Also, we know that the above condition is equivalent to the following time-domain condition:

$$\int_0^{\infty}y(t)^Ty(t)dt<\gamma \int_0^{\infty}u(t)^Tu(t)dt$$

where $\forall u\in \mathcal{L}_2$, i.e., square integrable. $y(t)=G(t)u(t)$ and of course $Y(j\omega) = G(j\omega)U(\omega)$

How to show this equivalence?  I try to write down the matrix form and have no idea how to use Parseval's theorem to explicitly obtain the result.

Comment: What's the relationship between $G,Y,$ and $U$? Do we have
$$
Y(j\omega ) = G(j \omega)U(j\omega)?
$$

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yes, you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use $*$ to refer to the "conjugate transpose".  With Parseval's theorem, we have
$$
\int_{0}^\infty y(t)^*y(t)\,dt = 
\int_{-\infty}^\infty Y(j\omega)^*Y(j\omega)\,d\omega \\
= \int_{-\infty}^\infty [G(j \omega)U(j \omega)]^*[G(j \omega)U(j \omega)]\,d\omega\\
= \int_{-\infty}^\infty U(j \omega)^*G(j \omega)^*G(j \omega)U(j \omega)\,d\omega
$$
Now, $G(j\omega)^*G(j\omega)\leq \gamma I$ means that for all vectors $v \in \Bbb C^n$, we have 
$$
v^*[G(j\omega)^*G(j\omega)]v \leq v^*[\gamma I]v = \gamma \,v^*v
$$
Thus, we have
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty U(j \omega)^*G(j \omega)^*G(j \omega)U(j \omega)\,d\omega\\
 \leq 
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \gamma U(j \omega)^*U(j \omega)\,d\omega  \\
= \gamma\int_{-\infty}^\infty  U(j \omega)^*U(j \omega)\,d\omega \\
= \gamma \int_{0}^\infty u(t)^*u(t)\,dt
$$
As desired.